# Where to find the % key in vim-adventures?

Tags: vim-adventures

I am in level 7 in vim-adventures. I need the % key to progress. I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

The `%` is locked up to the left of the `if(practice){perfect}` puzzle. You'll need a key to unlock it.

To solve the `if(practice){perfect}`, you'll need either `%` or `g`, both are locked up. You'll have to unlock one, solve the puzzle, get another key, then unlock the other.

[image: where to find % key]